# cannot convert string in array format such as "[55]" to array

Tags: javascript

I receive the following from another server in my payload as query param:

```
"[55]"
```

Now I want to convert it to an array in JavaScript,

Here is what I do:

```
var termssValidation= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.termsQuery));
```

But when I run the following:

```
for(var t in termssValidation ){
    console.log(termssValidation[t]);
}
```

I get 3 lines as follows:

```
[
5
5
]
```

How can I convert the above to an array properly?

Comment: Why are you stringifying the result? It should work if you only JSON.Parse it

Comment: Why are you stringify-ing a string? --- `JSON.parse("[55]")` works just fine.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I will give a try without that and let u guys know the result

Comment: I think you are doing the for iteration wrong, why don't try `console.log(t)` inside the `for` loop

Comment: @RokumDev because that would only print the index. That kind of `for` does not behave like a `foreach` in perl, for example.

Comment: @federico-klez-culloca thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need just to parse the [JSON](http://json.org/) string.

```js
console.log(JSON.parse('[55]'));
```

Comment: Just a question lets say if I send [xxxx] then in this case if I do not use JSON.stringify I get unexpected token. So is there any way that I can convert to array for both [55] and ["55"]?

Comment: if you expect an array, you could check with `Array.isArray` and if not, parse the string.

Comment: so if I send [xxxx] and if I stringify it and the parse will it convert to array?

Comment: wihthout knowing more, yes, it should.

Answer (score 3):

`JSON.stringify` is excess

```js
let j = JSON.parse("[55]")
console.log(j)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the inner JSON.stringify().
This method converts the "[66]" into ""[66]"". JSON.parse then converts this string as if the inner quotes were escaped. So the result is the original string "[66]".
Because the String in javascript is an iterable you get the individual characters as the result of the iteration.

This is the solution to your problem:

```
var termssValidation= JSON.parse(event.termsQuery);
```

Comment: Well, if this is not a detailed answer! I wish more answers on SO were like this.

Comment: Just a question lets say if I send [xxxx] then in this case if I do not use JSON.stringify I get unexpected token. So is there any way that I can convert to array for both [55] and [xxx]?

Comment: @HamedMinaee: Do you mean the literal character "x"? What are you expecting to happen when you parse [xxxx]?

Comment: There is a difference between literal String, literal Number and identifier. Considering [xxxx] in this form, the xxxx in the array would be an identifier but for JSON.parse it is only an illegal token as the stringified JSON has no connection to the outer scope. You would have to write it ["xxxxx"]. Then you would have an array with member "xxxxx" at position 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur awesome clarification :)

Answer (score 2):

This code works!

```js
let a = "[55]";

a = JSON.parse(a);

for (let i in a) {
  console.log(a[i]); //55
}
```